# convert from two bytes to a float

Tags: c, type-conversion

I try to write a function that takes two bytes and converts them to a float. My function takes short_buffer, which is an array of signed chars, converts each two adjacent values in it to a float, and then put it in data_float. This function works only if the float values are positive (only for unsigned chars), and for negative values I get a wrong answer, I guess it because of an overflow.
How can I fix it so that it will work for negative floats as well?
Here is my code:

```
void short_2_float( char* short_buffer, int size_of_short_buffer, float* data_float )
{
    int data_in_channel =0;
    
    for(int  i = 0, k=0; i < size_of_short_buffer ; i+=2, k++)
    {
        data_in_channel = (short_buffer[i] & 0x00ff) | (short_buffer[i + 1] << 8);
        data_float[k] = (float)data_in_channel / 32768.0;

    }
}
```

Example for results I got:

short_buffer[0]= 14, short_buffer [1] = 0  real data_float[0] value  = 0.000427,   my data_float[0] value =  0.000427

short_buffer[2] = 209, short_buffer [3] = 252  real data_float[1] value  = -0.024872, my data_float[1] value =  1.975128

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try using `unsigned char`.

Comment: what does a negative value in `short_buffer` mean then?

Comment: Then cast the value to `unsigned char` before performing any operation on it.

Comment: It doesn't work @dbush

Comment: So we need more information.  Update your question with a [mcve] which includes input, expected output, and actual output.

Comment: @ShirB it works see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Values larger than 127 in your `char` array are converted to negative values.  So when you do this:

```
short_buffer[i + 1] << 8
```

The value in `short_buffer` is first promoted to `int`.  So for example 252 is converted to -4 when stored (0xfc) which as an `int` is 0xfffffffc and shifting left by 8 gives you 0xfffffc00 (actually this is undefined behavior because you're left-shifting a negative value).

As mentioned in the comments, if you cast this value to `unsigned char` before doing anything else it will be converted to the value 252 and the calculation will work.

```
void short_2_float( char* short_buffer, int size_of_short_buffer, float* data_float )
{
    int data_in_channel =0;

    for(int  i = 0, k=0; i < size_of_short_buffer ; i+=2, k++)
    {
        data_in_channel = (short_buffer[i] & 0x00ff) | 
                          ((unsigned char)short_buffer[i + 1] << 8);
        printf("data=%d\n", data_in_channel);
        data_float[k] = (float)data_in_channel / 32768.0;

    }

}
```

Comment: "alues larger than 127 in your char array are converted to negative values":  Isn't it "may be converted" since it's impelmetnation dependent whether char is signed or not ?

Comment: @Christophe True, but if `char` wasn't signed in OP's implementation they wouldn't have had this problem.

Comment: @dbush I afraid it will not work https://godbolt.org/z/zz9b95

Comment: The question “How can I fix it so that it will work for negative floats as well?” indicates OP wants inputs with the high bit set to result in negative values in the `float` result.

Answer (score 0):

If 2 consecutive char are one short then access the char array with a short pointer and then do the conversion :

```
void short_2_float( char* short_buffer, int size_of_short_buffer, float* data_float )
{
short *shorts = short_buffer // enable to access the short_buffer every 2 chars

for(int  i = 0; i < size_of_short_buffer/2 ; i++)
{
    data_float[i] = (float)shorts(i) / 32768.0;

}
}
```

In case the order of char is inverse you need an inversion :

void short_2_float( char* short_buffer, int size_of_short_buffer, float* data_float )
{

```
for(int  i = 0; i < size_of_short_buffer/2 ; i++)
{
    char twoChars[2]
    twoChars[0] = short_buffer[2*i+1] // depends on the order of char in the short
    twoChars[1] = short_buffer[2*i] // depends on the order of char in the short
    short *aShort = twoChars // read the 2 chars as a short
    data_float[i] = (float)*aShort / 32768.0;

}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int main(void)
{
    unsigned char x[2] = {209,0xfc};

    short y = x[0] | (unsigned short)(x[1] << 8); 
    printf("%hi %hx %f\n", y, y, (float)y / 32768.0f);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/P33f7f

The result:

```
-815 fcd1 -0.024872
```

```
int main(void)
{
    char x[2] = {209,0xfc};
    unsigned char *uc = x;

    short y = uc[0] | (unsigned short)(uc[1] << 8); 
    printf("%hi %hx %f\n", y, y, (float)y / 32768.0f);
}
```

or union punning

```
typedef union
{
    short x;
    char b[2];
}shortu;
 
int main(void)
{
    char x[2] = {209,252};
    shortu z;

    z.b[0] = x[0];
    z.b[1] = x[1];

    printf("%f\n", (float)z.x / 32787.0f);

}
```

Comment: In `short y = x[0] | (unsigned short)(x[1] << 8);`, the right-hand side is not representable in 16-bit `short` when the high bit of `x[1]` is set, and the conversion to `short` is implementation-defined.

Answer (score -1):

The main problem is that the signedness of the upper byte is not handled correctly.

The following line has a problem:

```
data_in_channel = (short_buffer[i] & 0x00ff) | (short_buffer[i + 1] << 8);
```

A correct way to handle the signedness is:

```
data_in_channel = (int16_t)((int)short_buffer[i] & 0x00ff) | ((unsigned)short_buffer[i + 1] << 8);
```

For clarity the `(int)` cast is inserted here. I suggest using casts when converting between differently sized integers.

Before converting to an `int` the compiler needs to know if the value should be sign extended or zero extended. This is decided by the type (the signedness) of the old value. in this case it is the type `char`. The signedness of char can vary on different platforms.
Note that the cast is different for each of the bytes. The lower byte is interpreted as an unsigned value the other as a signed value. Casting can sometimes *add* set bits, when casting between signed ints. These bits are removed from the lower byte by the and operation. For the upperbyte we currently dont care about sign extension. we only care about bringing the bits into the correct location. Shifting negative values to the left is UB, so we use the unsigned shift instead, which is defined always. Now we want to interpret the uppermost bit of the input as the sign, that is the 16th bit. We do this by ignoring the upper 16 bits of the `int` and truncating/converting it down to a 16 bit signed int.

Using `short/uint16_t` directly in following way could also solve the problem:

```
void short_2_float( char* short_buffer, int size_of_short_buffer, float* data_float )
{
    int data_in_channel =0;
    
    for(int  i = 0, k=0; i < size_of_short_buffer ; i+=2, k++)
    {
        data_in_channel = (short_buffer[i] & 0x00ff) | ((unsigned)short_buffer[i + 1] << 8);
        data_float[k] = (float)(short)data_in_channel / 32768.0; // cast == interpret 16th bit as sign

    }
}
```

or directly use the `short`/`int16_t` type for `data_in_channel`. Remember that `int16_t` is defined in the standart lib.

Comment: For values the OP is interested in, those that would produce a negative result, the conversion to `int16_t` is implementation-defined by C 2018 6.3.1.3 3, and therefore this code is not guaranteed to work by the C standard. Also note the standard specifies conversions between integer types in terms of values, not in terms of bits in the representations; it does not say they are sign extended or zero extended.

Answer (score -1):

C semantics are tricky with signed integers, shifts, and conversions. Here is a correct method to assembly two `char` values into a signed result that is then scaled for your `float` range.

```
/*  This code assumes char is eight bits (or at least that the values in
    short_buffer contain only eight-bit values).
*/


#include <stdint.h>


static void short_2_float(
    char *short_buffer, int size_of_short_buffer, float *data_float)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size_of_short_buffer; i += 2)
    {
        //  First, we combine the bytes to make an unsigned 16-bit number.
        int32_t t = (unsigned char) short_buffer[i]
            | (unsigned char) short_buffer[i+1] << 8;

        /*  At this point, t contains an unsigned 16-bit number.  If bit 15 is
            clear, t is the number we want.  If it is set, we want its two’s
            complement value, t - 0x10000.

            Flipping the bit gives us t + 0x8000 (if the bit goes from 0 to 1)
            or t - 0x8000 (if it goes from 1 to 0).

            Then subtracting 0x8000 gives us either t or t - 0x10000, the
            desired result, which we then scale to the desired range.

            The final statement could also be:
                *data_float++ = t * 0x1p-15f - 1;
        */
        t ^= 0x8000;
        *data_float++ = (t - 0x8000) * 0x1p-15f;
    }
}


#include <stdio.h>
 
 
int main(void)
{
    char x[] = { 14, 0, 209, 252 };
    float y[sizeof x / 2];
    short_2_float(x, sizeof x, y);
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof x / 2; ++i)
        printf("y[%d] = %.99g\n", i, y[i]);
}
```